# Neither the_excerpt() nor the_content() works properly?

Tags: search, archives, content, excerpt

I'm wondering what should be used in index.php (post listing page): `the_excerpt()` or `the_content()`?

1. Twenty Thirteen uses `the_content()` but this prints entire content unless `<!--more-->` exists and it completely ignores Excerpt field from [Posts > Add New > Excerpt].
2. So, I used `the_excerpt()` instead but this doesn't react to `<!--more-->` tag at all and it just grabs first 55 words or uses manual Excerpt and doesn't produce "Read more..." link.

What I would like to achieve is this:

- print 55 words
- but react to `<--more-->`
- and if manual excerpt is specified, use this instead (most people don't want the beginning of their post to be their excerpt so this is of crucial importance)
- produce optional "Read more..." link

This looks like the most intuitive to me for post listing pages. Does something like this exist?

If not, should `the_content()` be used on post listing pages? I think that most theme users aren't familiar with `<--more-->` tag and they rather expect that themes will create proper excerpts for post listing pages rather than displaying full post content.

Reference:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt
- ​http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-excerpt-teaser/

Comment: "but react to <--more-->" - react how? "produce optional "Read more..." link" - optional depending on what?

Comment: @Rarst "but react to <--more--> - react how?" - cut it earlier if user specifies this tag at certain end of sentence (to avoid sentences cut in the middle); "produce optional "Read more..." link - optional depending on what?" - entirely on developer's choice - current `the_excerpt()` doesn't allow "Read more..." as a function parameter and only `the_content()` does allow that. Developers need this for excerpts as well (well, this can be added separately but why then it became a part of `the_content()` already but not `the_excerpt()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements slant towards using `the_excerpt()` with adding read more link by custom code:

- *print 55 words* - already this by default and adjustable via `excerpt_length` filter
- *but react to `<!--more-->`* - this already happens, auto-generated excerpt cannot be longer than *teaser* (part from start of post to `<!--more-->` tag)
- *and if manual excerpt is specified, use this instead* - already works like this
- *produce optional "Read more..." link* this is one thing excerpt doesn't do natively. Can be added via:

  - `excerpt_more` filter, note it is only used if post was cut
  - `get_the_excerpt` or `the_excerpt` to append to any excerpt
  - in template, separately for excerpt template tag call

Comment: Thanks! This works! But there's one thing I missed: I'd like to also add an ability to parse HTML like `the_content()` does. So, basically, I would prefer it to be `the_content()` that uses manual excerpt if specified and auto-cuts the content at 55 words.

Comment: @Paul not impossible (`the_content` filter and do whatever you want to it), but you will really be bending it very far to achieve something excerpt does already (and as you can see in my post you referenced - there is plenty of logic going on in there).